# Check ID Exist and delete record in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

What I have to do is, whenever a `STORE_CODE` is entered it will check in the db and delete the store code. SO for that, I have written a procedure which is as below

```
PROCEDURE DELETE_STORE_INFO
(
  P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2
)

  AS

    BEGIN

    UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO set ISACTIVE = 'N' where STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;

    END DELETE_STORE_INFO;
```

But here what missing is

> what if the user enter the wrong `store_code` and does the operation so what it will do. how to check with that part ?

I guess something for `COUNT` wont work at this stage. Kindly suggest

Comment: So you build a logic to check if input string passed is valid or not. Let us know what format you are expecting then you can do a check before using it in delete statement

Comment: @XING: yes, which format you are talking about ? datatype of columns ?

Comment: You are passing your input as `NVARCHAR2`, so that shows that your code has some special double byte charaters and hence column has to be `NVARCHAR2`. Am talking about format / pattern of your `STORE_CD` which you want to verify against the input string to check if its valid or not

Comment: [SQL%ROWCOUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS99956)

Comment: also, `update ....returning isactive into o_isactive` maybe the case, but question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to find out how many rows were affected by the previous SQL statement:

```
PROCEDURE DELETE_STORE_INFO
(
  P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO
  SET    ISACTIVE   = 'N'
  WHERE  STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Store code does not exist.' );
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Store code does not exist.' );
  END IF;
END DELETE_STORE_INFO;
/
```

You can use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( string )` to output to the SQL console (if you are calling this from an external language like PHP or Java then you will not see the output and you may not see it in the console if you have `SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF`).

You could also use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( error_code, error_message )` to raise an exception if something invalid happens.

Alternatively you could return a status in an `OUT` parameter:

```
PROCEDURE DELETE_STORE_INFO
(
  P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,
  O_STATUS     OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO
  SET    ISACTIVE   = 'N'
  WHERE  STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    o_status := 0;
  ELSE
    o_status := 1;
  END IF;
END DELETE_STORE_INFO;
/
```

Comment: which one is better 1st answer or second ?

Comment: @VVVV Neither is "better" - they have different goals. If you want information on whether it succeeded but don't want to be able to act on that information programmatically (i.e. just for debugging) then you can use `DBMS_OUTPUT`. If not deleting the item is an error then use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` (but remember to catch the error in your scripts). If you want to know whether something was deleted or not in later parts of your scripts (but not deleting it is not an error) then return the status in the out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Generally contract for your procedure is: caller gives some `store_code` and procedure guarantee that there is no active store with such code. What if caller gives the wrong `store_code`? It means there is no such store, so contract is accomplished. You should do nothing, no more :)

But if you wish to check whether update found the record or not, you can add something like

```
if sql%notfound then
  dbms_output.put_line('There is no such store!');
end if;
```

immediately after update statement.

---

Especially for MT: just check simple script

```
create table t$(id integer);

insert into t$ values(1);

set serveroutput on

begin
  update t$ set id = 2 where id = 1;
  if sql%notfound
    then dbms_output.put_line('#1: not found');
    else dbms_output.put_line('#1: found');
  end if;
  update t$ set id = 4 where id = 3;
  if sql%found then
    dbms_output.put_line('#2: found');
    else dbms_output.put_line('#2: not found');
  end if;
end;
/

drop table t$;
```

My results are

```
Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 

#1: found
#2: not found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: It WILL work. Best practise is to check such affirmations before making them public. Just try script I placed above.

Answer (score 0):

There are something missunderstand in your request: you said you want to delete it but in the code, you just updated the store as incative.

Here is the proceure with both situation. You choose the right one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_STORE_INFO (P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2) AS
   n_count number;

BEGIN

   select count(1) INTO n_count from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO where STORE_CODE = p_store_code;

    if n_count > 0 then 
        UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO set ISACTIVE = 'N' where STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;

-- or for deletion
-- DELETE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO set ISACTIVE = 'N' where STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the required store was not found');
    end if;
END DELETE_STORE_INFO;
```